# Guideline/scheme for naming properties in GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, specification, fields-attributes

Are there any guidelines/requirements for naming properties in GeoJSON? Should I add a vendor-prefix for my properties which only make in use with a specific application?

I already read the specification however I didn't found any further information on this matter.

**Examples:**

```
{
    "foobar-id": 21
}
```

or

```
{
    "com.foobar": {
        "id": 21
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are valid GeoJSON, but most software tend to use the former. Additionally a GeoJSON file in the former format can be converted to other formats likes KML & Shapefile etc.

So I'll suggest that you use the former format, unless you have some specific reason to use the latter format.